# A let in a cond in scheme possible?

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a problem I don't understand how `let` works in a `cond`, with an `if` I understand it but not with a `cond`...

Here's my code with a `let`:

```lisp
(define add2
  (lambda (l) 
    (cond ((null? l) l)
     (let ((R (add2 (cdr l))))
       ((list? (car l)) (cons (add2 (car l)) R))
       ((number? (car l)) (cons (+ 2 (car l)) R))
       (else (cons (car l) R))))))
```

When I try it on my list, it doesn't work.

Normally when I give my list:

```lisp
(add2 '(2 b (10 a (56 3) 5) 4))
```

It should give me this :

```lisp
(4 b (12 a (58 5) 7) 6))
```

It doesn't...  It says: `let: bad syntax`

I think it might be this but I checked every parentheses and didn't see something missing...

But when I remove my `let` and try without it, it works!

```lisp
(define add2
  (lambda (l) 
    (cond ((null? l) l)
      ((list? (car l)) (cons (add2 (car l)) (add2 (cdr l))))
      ((number? (car l)) (cons (+ 2 (car l)) (add2 (cdr l))))
      (else (cons (car l) (add2 (cdr l)))))))
```

`(add2 '(2 b (10 a (56 3) 5) 4))` into `(4 b (12 a (58 5) 7) 6))`

Therefore I don't understand why it doesn't work and I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Being consistent with adding spaces after identifiers instead of leaving them out at random would help make your code a lot more readable, btw.

Comment: I added spaces because my eyes couldn't stand it.

Comment: hahaha, I didn't understand how to send the code at first x) They said I needed to do ctrl+k but it didn't work so I tried everything to post it.
I'll be more careful from now on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make your own syntax - but you have to follow the `cond` syntax
which says:

```
(cond ((condition-1 consequent-1)
       (condition-2 consequent-2)
       ...
       (else final-consequent)))
```

So there is no room for a `let` which you can place into it.

### Recapitulating what you want actually

You want to add 2 to only the numeric elements in a nested.
Such recursive functions dealing with nested lists (trees) traditionally have a `*` at their end of their name.

And let this function be tail-recursive.
We would define it first without `let`:

```
(define (add2* l (acc '())) 
  (cond ((null? l) (reverse acc))
        ((list? (car l)) (cons (add2* (car l)) (add2* (cdr l))))
        ((number? (car l)) (cons (+ 2 (car l)) (add2* (cdr l))))
        (else (cons (car l) (add2* (cdr l))))))
```

Using `let`, you want to save some typing. Do it by nesting two cond expressions:

```
(define (add2* l (acc '())) 
  (cond ((null? l) (reverse acc))
        (else (let ((R (add2* (cdr l))))
                (cond ((list? (car l)) (cons (add2* (car l)) R))
                      ((number? (car l)) (cons (+ 2 (car l)) R))
                      (else (cons (car l) R)))))))
```

You could use `if` for the outer `cond`:

```
(define add2
  (lambda (l) 
    (if (null? l) 
        l
        (let ((R (add2 (cdr l))))
          (cond ((list? (car l)) (cons (add2 (car l)) R))
                ((number? (car l)) (cons (+ 2 (car l)) R))
                (else (cons (car l) R)))))))
```

Whish is the same like:

```
(define (add2 l) 
  (if (null? l) 
      l
      (let ((R (add2 (cdr l))))
        (cond ((list? (car l)) (cons (add2 (car l)) R))
              ((number? (car l)) (cons (+ 2 (car l)) R))
              (else (cons (car l) R))))))
```

### Generalization by `map-tree`

This thing is actually a map-tree:

```
(define (map-tree func tree (acc '()))
  (cond ((null? tree) (reverse acc))
        ((list? (car tree)) (cons (map-tree func (car tree)) (map-tree func (cdr tree))))
        (else (cons (func (car tree)) (map-tree func (cdr tree))))))
```

And using this more general function, you define your `add2*` by:

```
(define (add2 x)
  (if (number? x) 
      (+ 2 x) 
      x))

(define (add2* tree)
  (map-tree add2 tree))
```

And test it:

```
(add2* '(2 b (10 a (56 3) 5) 4))                                              
;; => '(4 b (12 a (58 5) 7) 6)
```

Generalization by `map-tree` makes it possible for you to define
other kind of such similar functions - since it decouples the
actual function applied to each element of the tree
from the traversal and application of the function on the tree.

e.g. you could define a `add5*` easily:

```
(define (add5 x)
  (if (number? x)
      (+ 5 x)
      x))

(define (add5* tree)
  (map-tree add5 tree))
```

### Generalize definition of `addN` and `addN*`

Since this also follows some pattern, you can let a function
return the corresponding `add7` and `add7*`:

```
(define (generate-addN n)
  (lambda (x)
    (if (number? x)
        (+ n x)
        x)))

(define (generate-addN* n)
  (lambda (tree)
    (map-tree (generate-addN n) tree)))
```

These functions generate you the functions for `addN` and `addN*`:

```
(define add7 (generate-addN 7))

(define add7* (generate-addN* 7))
```

### Or write a general `addN*` function

Or you directly define and use a generalized `addN*` function which takes `n` and the `tree` as its arguments:

```
(define (addN* n tree)
  (map-tree (generate-addN n) tree))
```

or write-out the `generate-addN` as a lambda expression:

```
(define (addN* n tree)
  (map-tree (lambda (x) 
              (if (number? x) 
                  (+ n x) 
                  x)) 
            tree))
```

And use it

```
(addN* 7 '(2 b (10 a (56 3) 5) 4))
;; => '(9 b (17 a (63 10) 12) 11)
```

### Other Use

You could also define a function which recursively adds at the
and of a string element the suffix: "_s".

```
(define (addS* s tree)
  (map-tree (lambda (x)
              (if (string? x)
                  (~a x s)
                  x))
            tree))

(addS* "_s" '(2 b (10 a ("abc" 3) "def") 4))
;; => '(2 b (10 a ("abc_s" 3) "def_s") 4)
```

Comment: I have a much fancier version of `map-tree` (And `leaf-map` which is the simpler option here) based on the [Serapeum Common Lisp library](https://github.com/ruricolist/serapeum/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#map-tree-fun-tree-key-tag-traversal) floating around but figured it was overkill.

Answer (score 1):

A `cond` has this structure:

```
(cond 
  [predicate consequent1 ... consequent-tail]
  ...
  [else alternative1 ... alternative-tail])
```

You code is automatically interpreted as this:

```
(cond
 [(null? l) l]
 [let                                      ; check the variable let if it's not #f
  ((R (add2 (cdr l))))                     ; call the procedure R and the call the procedure R should return
  ((list? (car l))(cons (add2 (car l)) R)) ; call list? and then call the procedure it should return
  ((number? (car l))(cons (+ 2 (car l))R)) ; call number? and then call the procedure it should return
  (else (cons (car l) R)]
))))
```

Now I understand what you are after. I've made this macro a long time ago that adds support for bindings in a `cond`:

```
(define-syntax defcond
  (syntax-rules (else bind define =>)
    ((_ "build" terms ())
     terms)
    ((_ "build" alternative ((bind (b e) ...) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (let ((b e) ...) alternative) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((bind name (b e) ...) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (let name ((b e) ...) alternative) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((define b e) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (letrec ((b e)) alternative) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((predicate consequent) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (if predicate consequent alternative) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((predicate consequent => (b e) ...) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (if predicate consequent (let ((b e) ...) alternative)) rest))
    ((_ "build" alternative ((predicate consequent) . rest))
     (defcond "build" (if predicate consequent alternative) rest))
    ((_ "maybe-else" ((else expression) . rest))
     (defcond "build" expression rest))
    ((_ "maybe-else" ((something expression) . rest))
     (defcond "build" #f ((something expression) . rest)))
    ((_ "reverse" terms ())
     (defcond "maybe-else" terms))
    ((_ "reverse" (fterms ...) (term1 terms ...))
     (defcond "reverse" (term1 fterms ...) (terms ...)))
    ((_ terms ...)
     (defcond "reverse" () (terms ...)))))
```

And using that I can write your code like this:

```
(define (add2 l)
  (defcond
    [(null? l) l]
    [bind (a (car l)) (d (cdr l))]
    [(list? a) (cons (add2 a) d)]
    [(number? a) (cons (+ 2 a) d)]
    [else (cons a d)]))
```

It also supports `letrec`/`define` and named `let` type of structure:

```
(define (reverse lst)
  (defcond 
    [bind loop (lst lst) (acc '())]
    [(null? lst) acc]
    [else (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc))]))
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is the best way to express bindings in a conditional so I haven't touched this since I wrote the macro in 2017 and it's been in my trash folder ever since :-p.

Comment: Probably better off using `match` in Racket, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Another, more advanced way to bind elements of a list to variables and execute code based on their type is to use pattern matching.

The following works with Racket (Might need a `(require racket/match)` depending on your `#lang`), Guile (With `(use-modules (ice-9 match))`), Chicken (With the [`matchable` egg](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/matchable)), and probably any other Scheme that supports [Wright-style pattern matching](https://web.archive.org/web/20170809083703if_/http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/103p1/pdf/match.pdf).

```lisp
(define (add2 l)
  (match l
    ('() '()) ; Empty list
    (`(,(? list? a) . ,rest) ; List where the car is a list?
     (cons (add2 a) (add2 rest)))
    (`(,(? number? a) . ,rest) ; List where the car is a number?
     (cons (+ a 2) (add2 rest)))
    (`(,a . ,rest) ; List where the car is some other type
     (cons a (add2 rest)))))
```

```lisp
> (add2 '(2 b (10 a (56 3) 5) 4))
'(4 b (12 a (58 5) 7) 6)
```